# how to change the content place in html pages without changing header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, dhtml

I have five html pages ,all pages have same search tab,header,footer,  my question is when enter particular searchtext and click search only the content place  where the output will be displayed has to be changed in the html pages without  change in header and footer.
I am using html ,javascript,jquery on clientside and webservices with c# coding on the server side

Comment: Are you using Master Pages? Are you getting data via ajax? Please provide more details on how you are working in this website.

Comment: @Obed, he says he is using html pages and jquery, so no masterpages and the updates will be via AJAX.  What we do need is to see the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am not using master pages ,i want my html to be pure html using only javascript or jquery with ajax call to the webservices  written in c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest answer would be to use jQuery's [.ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) or [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Look at those and, if you have a specific problem implementing them we can help out.